# Dynamically add href based on Class name of parent list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add a `href` attribute to an anchor tag based on the class name of its parent list item.
Example: Here is what I need:

```
<li class="prefix_1"><a href="prefix_1">myText</a></li>
<li class="prefix_2"><a href="prefix_2">myText</a></li>
<li class="prefix_3"><a href="prefix_3">myText</a></li>
```

I should also add that I am dynamically adding the class names to the list items using `jQuery` like this:

```
$("ul.tabs-nav").children().each(function(i) {
   $(this).addClass("prefix_" + (i+1));
});
```

Comment: What are you starting with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$("ul.tabs-nav").children().each(function(i) {
   var $this = $(this); // don't look for the same element twice
   $this.addClass("prefix_" + (i+1));
   $this.find('a').attr('href', 'prefix_' + (i+1)); // find the link and add href
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set the attribute of the anchor like

```
$("ul.tabs-nav").children().each(function(i) {
   $(this).addClass("prefix_" + (i+1));
   $(this).find('[href]').attr('href', 'prefix_' + (i+1));
});
```

```js
$("ul.tabs-nav").children().each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass("prefix_" + (i + 1));
  $(this).find('[href]').attr('href', 'prefix_' + (i + 1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs-nav">
  <li class="prefix_1"><a href="prefix_1">myText</a>
  </li>
  <li class="prefix_2"><a href="prefix_2">myText</a>
  </li>
  <li class="prefix_3"><a href="prefix_3">myText</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```