# jquery add href based on class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on the below link as an example:

...if a link tag contains the class "add-selected", I want jquery to add an href called "#scrollTo" to all corresponding 's.

```
<a class="add-selected btn btn-default" href="#">
    <span class=" ion-plus-circled"></span>Add Selected
</a>
```

Final result after page loads should be:

```
<a class="add-selected btn btn-default" href="#scroll">
    <span class=" ion-plus-circled"></span>Add Selected
</a>
```

Comment: Okay, and where is your attempt first? StackOverflow isn't a coding service, we're here to help, not to do it all for you.

Comment: It's a bit unclear if you want `#scrollTo` or `#scroll`. (Different in question and in HTML).

Comment: Searching for `add href based on class` ► https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30981092/dynamically-add-href-based-on-class-name-of-parent-list-item - While that answer shows parent elements it is shown there how to replace a `href` value based on a class selector. - Try that and if you have issues you can post your code with the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$(function(){
   $('a.add-selected').attr('href','#scrollTo');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.add-selected').attr('href', '#scroll');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="add-selected btn btn-default" href="#">
    <span class=" ion-plus-circled"></span>Add Selected
</a>
<br/>
<a class="add-selected btn btn-default" href="#">
    <span class=" ion-plus-circled"></span>Add Selected
</a>
<br/>
<a class="add-selected btn btn-default" href="#">
    <span class=" ion-plus-circled"></span>Add Selected
</a>
<br/>
<a class="add-selected btn btn-default" href="#">
    <span class=" ion-plus-circled"></span>Add Selected
</a>
```